# hook_node_view is not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I am building a module for drupal 8 which needs to use `hook_node_view`. I tried the following code:-

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Demonstrates the possibilities of forms in Drupal 8.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function demo_form_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Found a form with ID %form_id', array('%form_id' => $form_id)));
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_view()
 */
function demo_form_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
   drupal_set_message(t('its working'));
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Only alters the Search form 'search_block_form'.
 */
function demo_form_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['hello'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('Go ahead, try me ...') . '<br />',
    '#weight' => -1,
  );
}
```

I can't see any message from `demo_form_node_view`, if the hook was correct than it should have shown the message. I am new to drupal and can't figure out why `demo_form_node_view` is not working.

Comment: Just in case... you need to clear Drupal caches after adding a new hook (e.g. `drush cr`). Also try replacing the set message line with a print/echo line, in case the hook is being called but the message isn't appearing for a different reason.

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't forget to clear caches. Second of all, please consider that an actual entity of type node has to be used somewhere in the page for that hook to fire. Since you are working with a form maybe you're not loading a node?

It's also possible that the hook is being called but `drupal_set_message` doesn't work because of a redirect or something clearing the messages (I don't know your environment enough). Try to `echo` something and then `exit;` immediately.

Finally you can try using `hook_entity_view` (which is the more generic version of `[hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view][1]` to see if you are a different effect.

Comment: Thanks, I tried hook_entity_view but it wasn't   working, 8 used echo and it shows the message.